# Missing boundary value in multipart/form-data

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am trying to upload file using jquery ajax (in IE 11) and it faile with a server error. In developer tools > Network tab > and if I select the POST request and go to Headers tab I see "Content-Type: multipart/form-data " and I ***don't see boundary value in header***. I tried contentType: undefined and contentType: false both didn't work. I am using jquery-1.11.0 if that matters. Here is a sample of my code. I am very new to all these and I must be missing something here.

**Html:**

```
 <form id="example-form" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
      file.type.id:
      <input type="text" name="file.type.id" value="3P">
      <br>        

      file.title:
      <input type="text" name="file.title" value="My File">
      <br>
      file.edition:
      <input type="text" name="file.edition" value="1">
      <br>

      file.format:
      <input type="text" name="file.format" value="txt">
      <br>
        <input type="file" name="fileContent" id="fileu">

         <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

**js**

```
function apicall(type, apiUrl, data, userID, contentType, dataType) {
    var request = jQuery.ajax({         
        type: type,
        url: apiUrl,                        
        headers: { 'user_Id': userID},          
        dataType: dataType,
        contentType: undefined,
        processData: false,
        data: data
    });
    return request;
}

function upload() {
    var formData = new FormData($('#example-form')[0]);
    var type = "POST";
    var url = "<post url>";

    //var contentType = "multipart/form-data";
    var contentType = undefined;
    var dataType = "json";
    var userId = "<unique User ID>";

    var fileUpload = apicall(type, url, formData, userId, contentType, dataType);
    $.when(fileUpload).done(function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        alert("hoho" + JSON.stringify(data));
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("err: " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR))
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to jquery latest version and that fixed it.